# Leaflet.js shrink getBounds()

Tags: leaflet, gis

Leafletjs has a function `pad(x)` for increasing the latLng bounds. How do I shrink it? I've tried putting a negative number in there with little success.

I'm basically trying to see if a marker is within the current view, and if not center on that marker. But some markers can be plotted right on the edge of view and still be classed as in view. I'm trying to add *inner* padding on the current viewport bounds to avoid this.

`if(!map.getBounds().pad(-1.5).contains(marker.getLatLng()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `paddingTopLeft`, `paddingBottomRight` or `padding` options of `L.Map`'s `fitBounds` method:

> Sets the amount of padding in the top left corner of a map container that shouldn't be accounted for when setting the view to fit bounds. Useful if you have some control overlays on the map like a sidebar and you don't want them to obscure objects you're zooming to.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-paddingtopleft

```
map.fitBounds(layer, {'padding': [n, n]})
```

Answer (score 0):

The negative value range for pad() is 0 to -0.5.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5741

edit: link basically states that pad takes in a ratio of 1 not a typical percentage value. So to decrease the bounds by 50% (which would visually make it 0, because the left bounds would go in 50% to the middle, and the right bounds would also go in 50% to the middle, etc) the parameter value would be pad(-0.5) NOT pad(-50)

to increase add a positive ratio.

Comment: Can you include a little more detail from the link, so that it is useful if the link gets broken?